# How to use a fetch in PHP

Tags: php, database, fetch

I've written the following code:

```
        <?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="formend";
$db_table="jadval";
$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `jadval`");
while ($amch = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult)) {
    echo $amch["id"];
    echo $amch["name"];
}
?>
```

But this does not work
Only one page was empty
plz help me ...

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Are you a beginner just learning PHP? are you following some kind of tutorial?  Perhaps @CharlotteDunois can recommend a tutorial for a basic CRUD application which uses PDO or similar? Let's be nice to the new kid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_*` instead as `mysql_*` has already been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "formend";
$db_table = "jadval";
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

$dbresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `jadval`");
while ($amch = mysqli_fetch_array($dbresult)) {
    echo $amch["id"];
    echo $amch["name"];
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` has been removed in PHP 7. It was deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yup, will update post, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

PDO will work on 12 different database systems, where as MySQLi will only work with MySQL databases. (from w3schools)

using PDO:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
}catch(PDOException $e){}
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM jadval");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
 print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
 $result = $sth->fetchAll();
 print_r($result);
```

I hope its helpful!

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code:

```
    <?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="formend";
$db_table="jadval";
$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jadval");
while ($amch = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult)) {
    echo $amch["id"];
    echo $amch["name"];
}
?>
```

instead of mysql_fetch_assoc, you should use mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: but mysql has been removed from PHP 7. try to use PDO

Comment: Nothing can not be displayed

Comment: Please post database structure and data image